# Dynamic form content and tinymce in symfony

Tags: symfony, tinymce

I have a tinymce issue. I use it for my textarea's in symfony. I realized following steps.

1. Include the tinymce JS in my base template

2 Set some configuration for tinymce

```
tinymce.init({
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        menubar: "format edit",
        editor_selector : "rte",
        plugins:  'emoticons textcolor',
        toolbar:  'emoticons forecolor backcolor',
        height :  300,
        theme :   'modern'
    });
```

3. Include class "rte" in my form element of type textarea

:

```
->add('writeto', 'collection', array(
    'type'         => new WritetoType() ,
    'allow_add'    => false,
    'allow_delete' => false,
    'label'        => false,
    'options'  => array(
    'required'  => false,
    'attr'      => array('class' => ''))
))
```

Now everything works fine. But if i add a new collection (exp. writTo element from above) then this have not the tinymce classes. What do I wrong?

Should i start a tinymce event for dynamic content?

Answer (score 0):

This part

```
 array('class' => '')
```

Should contain the `rte` class, ie:

```
 array('class' => 'rte')
```

Comment: Ok if i add the class "rte" i see the Tinymce RTE on my textarea. But if i dynamic add new collection item "writeTo" this do not have the TinyMCE.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue.

1. I create a function for init my tiny mce and call this on document load:

   ```
   function initRTE()
   {
       // Integrate tinymce into textarea
       tinymce.init({
           mode : "specific_textareas",
           menubar: "format edit",
           editor_selector : "rte",
           plugins:  'emoticons textcolor',
           toolbar:  'emoticons forecolor backcolor',
           height :  300,
           theme :   'modern'
       });
   }
   ```
2. After i add a new collection i call the init function again and my new items get the tinymce functions